# LeetCode continues method after return

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, return

This creates the problem that my pointer ends up outside the array. But when I run my program in VS Code this doesn't happen.

LeetCode question nr. 42

Explanation: The above elevation map (black section) is represented by array [0,1,0,2,1,0,1,3,2,1,2,1]. In this case, 6 units of rain water (blue section) are being trapped.

Used Array for both tests.

```
j = { 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1 }
```

VS Code Methode

```
private static int Trap(int[] height)
        {
            int rechts = 1;
            int links = 0;
            int zwischen = 0;
            int erg = 0;
            while (links <= height.Length - 1)
            {

                while (height[links] > height[links + rechts])
                {
                    zwischen += (height[links] - height[links + rechts]);
                    rechts++;
                    if (links + rechts > height.Length - 1)
                    {
                        zwischen = 0;
                        rechts = 1;
                        links++;
                    }
                    if (links >= height.Length - 1)
                    {
                        return erg;
                    }

                }
                if (height[links] <= height[links + rechts])
                {
                    erg += zwischen;
                    Console.WriteLine(" links = " + links + " rechts = " + rechts + " zwischen = " + zwischen + " erg = " + erg);
                    zwischen = 0;
                    links += rechts;
                    rechts = 1;
                }
            }
            return erg;

        }
```

Console

```
 links = 0 rechts = 1 zwischen = 0 erg = 0
 links = 1 rechts = 2 zwischen = 1 erg = 1
 links = 3 rechts = 4 zwischen = 4 erg = 5
 links = 8 rechts = 2 zwischen = 1 erg = 6
 6
```

LeetCode

```
public int Trap(int[] height) {
            int rechts = 1;
            int links = 0;
            int zwischen = 0;
            int erg = 0;
            while (links <= height.Length - 1)
            {

                while (height[links] > height[links + rechts])
                {
                    zwischen += (height[links] - height[links + rechts]);
                    rechts++;
                    if (links + rechts > height.Length - 1)
                    {
                        zwischen = 0;
                        rechts = 1;
                        links++;
                    }
                    if (links >= height.Length - 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("hi");
                        return erg;
                    }

                }
                if (height[links] <= height[links + rechts])
                {
                    erg += zwischen;
                    Console.WriteLine(" links = " + links + " rechts = " + rechts + " zwischen = " + zwischen + " erg = " + erg);
                    zwischen = 0;
                    links += rechts;
                    rechts = 1;
                }
            }
            return erg;
        }
```

Console same array

```
 links = 0 rechts = 1 zwischen = 0 erg = 0
 links = 1 rechts = 2 zwischen = 1 erg = 1
 links = 3 rechts = 4 zwischen = 4 erg = 5
 links = 8 rechts = 2 zwischen = 1 erg = 6
"hi"
 links = 0 rechts = 5 zwischen = 9 erg = 9
```

Error

```
Unhandled exception. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
At Solution.Trap(Int32[] height)
At __Driver__.Main(String[] args)
```

I know that the VS Code function is static and LeetCode isnt. But both should stop executing after the return statement. I even tried (LeetCode) changing the condition of the last if statement where I add zwischen on to erg. My solution to that was that I added an boollean "fertig" in front of the retun statement. So that the last if statment doesnt execute again, but it still did.

```
(height[links] <= height[links + rechts] && fertig = false)
```

Addition
I tried debugging each line ( ending )

```
if (links >= height.Length - 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("end1 " + erg);
                    return erg;
                }
```

I let my program display the result and which return statement it uses (shown by erg).

```
 links = 0 rechts = 1 zwischen = 0 erg = 0
 links = 1 rechts = 2 zwischen = 1 erg = 1
 links = 3 rechts = 4 zwischen = 4 erg = 5
 links = 8 rechts = 2 zwischen = 1 erg = 6
end1 6 //Value 6 is correct. But the code doesnt terminate after return.
 links = 0 rechts = 5 zwischen = 9 erg = 9
end2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer works for the first input, but it's running both of the test cases. Try your code in VS with the follow input and you'll see:
`height = [4,2,0,3,2,5]`

If you just want a hint without the solved answer, I'd recommend adding boundary checks on the `height` array, or debugging line-by-line with the array listed above..

Comment: First of all, thank you. Your tip helped me initially until the problem arose again, that the code was not aborted after return. I'll describe the circumstances in case you want to watch it again. If not, that's ok too, thanks in any case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what changed, but after I opened my browser again a few hours later, everything suddenly worked again. Maybe leetcode just had a few bugs when compiling

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!